# Download and write .tar.gz files without corruption

Tags: ruby, http, file, download

How do you download files, specifically .zip and .tar.gz, with Ruby and write them to the disk?

<sub>—
*This question was originally specific to a bug in MacRuby, but the answers are relevant to the above general question.*</sub>

<sub>Using MacRuby, I've found that the file appears to be the same as the reference (in
size), but the archives refuse to extract. What I'm attempting now is at: https://gist.github.com/arbales/8203385
Thanks!</sub>

Comment: Size doesn't matter. The only way you're going to find out what you're doing wrong is by looking at the content. I'd suggest debugging with a small test file full of a simple repeating pattern.

Comment: If I open the files in TextMate, they appear the same...

Comment: Have you tried using `open-uri`?

Comment: What's with the `filePath:path` syntax? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: @Geo, it's Ruby 1.9.1's named parameter syntax thing — I'm writing a MacRuby application, so I can use native Cocoa widgets.

Comment: Really braindead question: are the checksums (md5sum or similar) of the files the same? Can you use something like xdelta to see how different the files are?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've successfully downloaded and extracted GZip files with this code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'zlib'

open('tarball.tar', 'w') do |local_file|
  open('http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master/tarball.tar.gz') do |remote_file|
    local_file.write(Zlib::GzipReader.new(remote_file).read)
  end
end
```

Comment: The .tar.gz file apparently isn't working. "mrb[2877:a0f] not in gzip format"

Comment: I changed the code to include the URL you had in your example, and it runs fine in Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.1, Rubinius 1.0.0 RC2 and JRuby 1.4.0. However, when run in MacRuby 0.5 it saves a garbled file. I don't know why, but it's definitely a bug in MacRuby.

Comment: I've also tried rewriting the code using HTTParty, with the same result (but HTTParty probably uses the same mechanisms as open-uri, so that's no surprise).

Comment: :-( I was afraid it was a MacRuby bug. Now I have to figure out some weird multi-step Cocoa way to download.

Comment: @theo, I can't vote up your answer for some reason, could you edit it so I can?

Comment: not sure why you can't upvote it, I haven't done anything as far as I can see

Comment: I tried to upvote after I already did, and it removed my vote, now I cant reup.

Comment: if you are using MacRuby, you can use NSTask to use curl to get the file as a workaround

Comment: I passed user name and password with this code for basic http authentication "open(uri, :http_basic_authentication=>[@username, @password])"

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using open-uri in ruby's stdlib.

```
require 'open-uri'

open(out_file, 'w') do |out|
  out.write(open(url).read)
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/classes/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#M000832

Make sure you look at the :progress_proc option to open as it looks like you want a progress hook.

Comment: It's a nice simple solution, and I've tried open-uri, and I still get a corrupted file.

Comment: Strange. I have a system using this at the moment that downloads all of the National Library of Medicine zip files (in parallel using resque) made up of >700 files, each of which is tens of Mb.

I would get them with curl or wget from a shell and ensure that there isn't a fundamental issue with the archives.

Comment: I did, when I download them with Curl, wget, or Safari, the archived expand just fine, but when I try anything in my app the files refuse to expand – they often create these empty .cpg or something files.

Comment: Using this simple method, I eventually had to add a header `{'Accept-encoding' => ''}` to the `open()` call, because `.tar.gz` downloads were being incorrectly inflated as part of the download process (like gzip encoding sent by a web server)

Comment: That is, the file I was saving to disk was the `.tar` uncompressed rather than the intended original `.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

The last time I got currupted files with Ruby was when I forgot to call `file.binmode` right after `File.open`. Took me hours to find out what was wrong. Does it help with your issue?

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation states that this is only useful in MSDOS, I'm running Mac OS, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When downloading a `.tar.gz`  with `open-uri`  via a simple `open()` call, I was also getting errors uncompressing the file on disk. I eventually noticed that the file size was much larger than expected.

Inspecting the file `download.tar.gz` on disk, what it actually contained was `download.tar` uncompressed; and that could be untarred. This seems to be due to an implicit `Accept-encoding: gzip` header on the `open()` call which makes sense for web content, but is not what I wanted when retrieving a gzipped tarball. I was able to work around it and defeat that behavior by sending a blank `Accept-encoding` header in the optional hash argument to the remote `open()`:

```
open('/local/path/to/download.tar.gz', 'wb') do |file|
  # Send a blank Accept-encoding header
  file.write open('https://example.com/remote.tar.gz', {'Accept-encoding'=>''}).read
end
```