# cannot extract the gz file that is downloaded

Tags: ruby, gzip

the gz file is downloaded but is not extractable. Here is a working program that downloads the file but itself cannot extract it.

```
    require 'open-uri'
require 'zlib'
(2017..2017).each{|year|
    (1..1).each{|weekno|
        symbols.each{|instrument|
            url="https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/#{instrument}/#{year}/#{weekno}.csv.gz"
            puts url
            begin
                open("#{instrument}#{year}#{weekno}.csv.gz", 'w') do |local_file|
                    open(url) do |remote_file|
                        local_file.write(Zlib::GzipReader.new(remote_file).read)
                                            end
                end
                Zlib::GzipReader.open("#{instrument}#{year}#{weekno}.csv.gz") {|gz|
                    print gz.read
                }
                            rescue StandardError => e  
                puts e.message  
                puts e.backtrace.inspect  
            end 
        }
    }
    }

I get error 
https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/AUDCAD/2017/1.csv.gz
not in gzip format
["downloadtickfiles.rb:26:in `initialize'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:26:in `open'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:16:in `each'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:15:in `each'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:15:in `block in <main>'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:14:in `each'", "downloadtickfiles.rb:14:in `<main>'"]
```

Comment: If you manually download the file or with curl are you able to gunzip it?

Comment: yes. i changed my code to use curl and it works now. bit convoluted but prob solved for now. 
Kernel.system "curl #{url} --output #{instrument}#{year}#{weekno}.csv.gz"

Zlib::GzipReader.open("#{instrument}#{year}#{weekno}.csv.gz") {|gz|
print gz.read

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar and indeed I have encountered it before downloading a .gz with `open()` - Try sending a blank accept-encoding header as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438120/541091